# Problema com Bootstrap Modal

Tags: asp.net-mvc

Olá!
Meu problema é o seguinte:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Esse é botão que chama o Modal Bootstrap:

```
<button class="btn btn-default details" data-id="@item.nome"><i class="fas fa-street-view"></i></button>
```

Essa é a página Modal Bootstrap;

```
<div class="modal-dialog">
<div class="modal-content">
    <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal"><span aria-hidden="true">×</span><span class="sr-only">Close</span></button>
        <h4 class="modal-title">Visitado em:</h4>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-body">
        <p>@Html.DisplayName("Nome")</p>
        <p>@Html.DisplayName("Data")</p>
        <p>@Html.DisplayName("Relatório")</p>
        <p>@Html.DisplayName("Cod Visita")</p>
        @foreach (var item in Model)
        {
            <p>@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.nome)</p>
            <p>@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Fecha)</p>
            <p>@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Relatorio)</p>
            <p>@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.id_visita)</p>
        }
    </div>
    <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Fechar</button>
    </div>
</div><!-- /.modal-content -->
```

Esse é meu controlador;

```
 DB_A3B4A6_estrangeirosEntities db2 = new DB_A3B4A6_estrangeirosEntities();
    public ActionResult IndexVisitas(string searchString)
    {
        var estrangeiros = from e in db2.Vw_RegistroVisita select e;
        if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(searchString))
        {
            estrangeiros = estrangeiros.Where(s => s.nome.Contains(searchString));
        }

        return View(estrangeiros.ToList());
        //return View(db2.Vw_RegistroVisita.ToList());
    }
```

Peço desculpas se não ficou muito claro ou se faltou mais informação. Sou novato em programação.

**Preciso fazer funcionar usando a variável.**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Primeiro voce deveria testar se o valor esta vindo correto no `$(this).attr("data-id")`, voce tambem pode testar `$(this).data("id")` caso seu jQuery seja maior que a versao 1.4.3

caso nao funcione confirar o valor que esta vindo nessa parte `data-id="@item.nome"`

Comment: É isso mesmo, alterei para $(this).data("id") . Obrigado!

Comment: @DPWSReceptivo nao esquece de marca como respondido :)

Comment: Onde marca "Respondido"?

Comment: no lado esquerdo da resposta, abaixo dos pontos tem uma imagem de checkin, so clikar nela :)